# Typing in Time Picker not fire onTimeSet

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I'm working with simple basic TimePickerDialog in android. When to show the picker, it sometimes picks analog and sometimes digital mode. The problem only happens when it shows digital mode in some device based on different os and devices. This problem occurs in some devices not all. If I move the wheel of digital mode, click OK to set the time, it wokrs fine. But when I write the time and click OK, it doesn't set time. But if I write down hour and then select minute part it works fine. I'm in Huawei Y7, api 24. Is it os related problem or device? Here is my code below:-

```
 new TimePickerDialog(context, listener, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        false).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Once you can set force fully it to clock mode:

Add `android:timePickerMode = "1"` for spinner mode

and

`android:timePickerMode="2"` for clock mode.

use this theme as in constructor of TimePickerDialog like this

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">clock</item>
</style>
```

**Note**: `android:timePickerMode` worked after API 21.

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(DateTimePickerDialogActivity.this, android.R.style.DialogTheme, onTimeSetListener, hour, minute, is24Hour);
```

Comment: How can I set android:timePickerMode="2" attribute in my java file?

Comment: Please check my edited answer and try to use that theme as input to Timepickerdialog.

Comment: No, my device still shows the spinner mode. Maybe it is a device-related problem. Thanks for your help.